# SQL Update Trigger with If Else logic with Multiple Rows

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, triggers, multiple-records

I'm having trouble getting my trigger to function with multiple records while also containing the if/else logic I need to conduct a test before inserting records.

My goal here is to enable a front end user of the system to change an event type between values 1,2, and 3, but if they change it to event type 1 then they must enter an occurrence date otherwise the transaction will be rolled back. If they do enter the occurrence date then the transaction will be entered. The below logic works for any 1 record updated through the front end, but the trouble is when multiple changes are written via SQL I receive the error:

"Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TG_tbl_LE_Event_Occurence_Date_Validation, Line 9 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
"

I know the trigger can be rewritten to account for multiple records, but I cannot find a way to write it where the If Else test still functions. Any input is appreciated.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_tbl_LE_Event_Occurence_Date_Validation]
    ON [dbo].[tbl_LE_Event]
    AFTER update
AS
DECLARE @InsertID int
SET @InsertID = (Select Event_ID from Inserted)

IF (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM inserted
WHERE inserted.Occurence_Date is null and inserted.Event_Type_ID = 1) > 0
BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RAISERROR('#####OCCURENCE DATE IS A REQUIRED FIELD FOR TYPE 1 EVENTS. PLEASE ENTER AN OCCURENCE DATE OR THIS CHANGE WILL NOT BE SAVED#####',10,1)
END ELSE 
    UPDATE dbo.tbl_LE_Event
    SET dbo.tbl_LE_Event.Event_Type_ID = Inserted.event_type_ID,
        dbo.tbl_LE_Event.Occurence_Date = Inserted.Occurence_Date
    FROM inserted  
    JOIN dbo.tbl_LE_Event ON dbo.tbl_LE_Event.Event_ID = @InsertID
```

GO

Comment: I cannot seem to recreate your error. This SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b381/2) does not seem to make the COUNT(*) test and adds null dates where event_type_id = 1. Wish I could be more help - will keep scratching my head.

Comment: Hello, thank you for looking. The if statement here attempts to see if a user is trying to change the event type to 1 but failed to enter an occurrence date. If this is the case, then roll back the transaction and raise an error. Else, proceed with updating the record/s.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error that occurred with multiple records. It seems the code did not like using variables for the ID, I'm including the revisions below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_tbl_LE_Event_Occurence_Date_Validation]
  ON [dbo].[tbl_LE_Event]
  AFTER update
  AS
     IF (SELECT count (*)FROM inserted
         WHERE inserted.Occurence_Date is null and inserted.Event_Type_ID = 1) >0
               BEGIN 
                rollback tran
                raiserror('#####OCCURENCE DATE IS A REQUIRED FIELD FOR LOSS EVENTS. PLEASE ENTER AN OCCURENCE DATE OR THIS CHANGE WILL NOT BE SAVED#####',10,1)
               END
     ELSE update dbo.tbl_LE_Event
        SET dbo.tbl_LE_Event.Event_Type_ID = Inserted.event_type_ID,
        dbo.tbl_LE_Event.Occurence_Date = Inserted.Occurence_Date
        from inserted join dbo.tbl_LE_Event on dbo.tbl_LE_Event.Event_ID = inserted.Event_ID


GO
```